# How to secure azure blobs

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am using windows azure blob storage service. I want to protect my blobs from public access (except my users).For this i used Shared Access Signature (SAS) and it works fine. But my issue is that i have a Container which contains blob in a directory structure, like :

```
  https://xxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/myContainer/directory1/blob1
  https://xxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/myContainer/directory1/blob2
  https://xxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/myContainer/directory1/blob3
  https://xxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/myContainer/directory1/blob4
  https://xxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/myContainer/directory1/blob5

  https://xxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/myContainer/directory2/blob1       
  https://xxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/myContainer/directory2/blob2      
  https://xxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/myContainer/directory2/blob3      
  https://xxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/myContainer/directory2/blob4      
  https://xxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/myContainer/directory2/blob5

  and so on...
```

Now my requirement is that i want to give public access to all blobs in `myContainer under directory2` but not to blobs which is under `directory1`, i want to keep all the blobs under directory1 as private. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create two containers.

One Private container with SAS on Container level and One public access container

```
  https://xxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/private/blob1
  https://xxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/private/blob2
  https://xxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/private/blob3
  https://xxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/private/blob4
  https://xxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/private/blob5

  https://xxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/public/blob1       
  https://xxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/public/blob2      
  https://xxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/public/blob3      
  https://xxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/public/blob4      
  https://xxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/public/blob5
```

Answer (score 3):

There are no directories in Azure blob storage.  Those "directories" you have now are just blobs with a `/` embedded in the name.  Since permissions are only at the container level, you'll have to create separate containers.

Answer (score 1):

You can only set permissions on container level, so you're left with two options.

Preferred option) Creat an additional public container and move your blobs.
Worse option) Create an seemingly endless valid sas link for all of your files.